# Python pandas dataframe's plot (Closed)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

i've finishing a plot from a .csv and looks like this:
[My plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OWin.png)

I am hoping to see like this:

[Finished plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCVId.png)

I've got 1 problems

1: How do i rename the x-axis to each set? (I've tried to rename my original data but I failed)

Comment: I've tried to use:

`New_df["Problem"].replace({"1": "Problem 1", "2": "Problem 2", "3": "Problem 3", "4": "Problem 4"}, inplace=True)`

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Use `xticks`

plt.xticks((0, 1, 2, 3), ('Problem 1','Problem 2','Problem 3','Problem 4'))
```

Comment: Thanks! ive used `plt.xticks(rotation=360)` did the rotation.